# Detect new DOM elements to use in .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following input fields:

```
subGroupInputs = $("td[data-field_name='sub_group'] input");
```

The user is able to add new inputs dynamically.

```
$(subGroupInputs).each(function(input) {
    $(this).on("keyup", function(){ 
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

I need to get all the values, even the values from the dynamically added ones but I cannot get the subGroupInputs to update.

I tried the below but that also does not work:

```
        function setVariables(){
             subGroupInputs = $("td[data-field_name='sub_group'] input");
        }

        //Initial Variables on Page Load
        setVariables();

        //Set Variables Again after new elements are added.
        $('.my-button').on("click", function(){ 
            setVariables();
        });
```

Comment: No, this does not work, it has the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try delegating try to put an id to the $('table') if you have multiple tables.

```
$("table").on('keyup', "td[data-field_name='sub_group'] input", function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

The idea here is the table gets all the event hits that are actually event propagated from `'td[data-field_name='sub_group'] input'`

Comment: Hi, thanks this works perfectly and is inline with the latest jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

you should try with [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of **on** if you want to bind with not-yet-added objects in jquery

Comment: Hi, thanks this did work but I am going with @joyBlanks's answer because the documentation states the following:
"As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method."